# How to get timing from the PgSQL DB

Tags: ruby, postgresql, timing, pg

I'm attempting to get the timing of a query using the pg gem. I saw the documentation, but I did not find anything. I want to know if there is something like `query.time`.

I added `\timing` to `~/.psqlrc`, so the command is active by default. If I write the query in the Postgres console the time is active.

This is the code:

```
conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'my_db') 
query=conn.exec('SELECT * from some_table')
puts query.num_tuples -> this work
puts query.time  -> undefined method
```

I need to measure the time of Postgres itself, I cannot use the Time class from Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as it should return the time back.

`puts conn.exec("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM some_table").values`

Comment: This does not appear to be correct. For my query, EXPLAIN ANALYZE returns 100ms, but the query is reported as 5,000ms when using `\timing` in the PSQL console.

Comment: It turns out the reason that \timing includes network time, and EXPLAIN ANALYZE does not.

Answer (score 1):

Although `PGconn.open(:dbname => 'my_db')` and `conn.exec` appears to work, it does not correctly report execution time. I suspect it reports the execution time for something besides the query. Perhaps it is the execution time of the EXPLAIN.

Although the question does not specify Rails, I suspect that using `PGconn` without Rails would have the same issue.

`PGconn.open(:dbname => 'my_db')` always reports the execution time between 0.010 and 0.285 ms. The correct execution time for my query was about 15,000ms.

To get the correct execution time use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...").values.last.first
```

To extract the numeric value:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...").values.last.first.scan( /\d+.\d+/ ).first
```

In terms of the OP,

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.execute('EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from some_table')
```